# Relationship calendar with simple facts table not showing date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Can someone please explain me why this relationship isn't working?
I have a calendar table with

```
ADDCOLUMNS(
CALENDARAUTO(),
...
)
```

Which contains a `date` column related to "`Document date`" in Table1. Both columns are "Date" type (also tried with Date/Time).

I get the following table:

The first column is "`Date`" from the `Calendar` table.
All other columns are from `Table1`.

Why is "Date" empty?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You relationship is a one-to-one relationship, so It hsould not have any problems in it, are you sure that there is a value in calendario for the date: 30-06-2018?, it seems like that your Table1 data only has one day in it `30-06-2018 23:59:59`

Comment: Because your calendar date time create 12:00:00 AM time format, Ideally there is nothing to match with the relation as both dates are different on time basis. Either convert your Table1 Date to just Date or adjust time on Canledario table. I hope it helps!!